# How to add header to multiple files using awk

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I would like to add a header line containing whitespaces to multiple files.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script name is "add_header.sh"
# ARG1 = HEADER STRING
# ARG2,3,... = ARRAY OF FILES TO ADD HEADER TO, RELATIVE DIRECTORY

HEADER=$1 
shift 

for FILE in $@; do
    awk -v HEADER=$HEADER FILE=$FILE 'BEGIN{print HEADER} {print}' FILE > FILE.new
done
```

Unfortunately, when I run it on my use case, it fails because of the white spaces:

```
touch file1 file2 file3
./add_header.sh "some header with spaces" file1 file2 file3
```

which gives following error:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `with' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: cannot open file `with' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: cannot open file `with' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Is there a way to escape white spaces inside a bash variable? I have tried using \ before each space, but the error now changes to:

```
./add_header.sh "some\ header\ with\ spaces" file1 file2 file3
awk: fatal: cannot open file `with\' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: cannot open file `with\' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: cannot open file `with\' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

which means the whitespaces are not being escaped.

Comment: Quote your strings

Comment: `FILE` does not exist. You need to use `"$FILE"` at the end of the command e.g `awk -v HEADER="$HEADER" -v FILE="$FILE" 'BEGIN{print HEADER} {print > FILE".new"}' "$FILE"`

Comment: Quote your variables `header="$1"`, `awk HEADER="$header" ...`. Avoid upper case variable names. Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator. I've combined your feedback with HatLess

Comment: @HatLess I indeed forgot to add the file argument. I also forgot to add a new `-v` flag for the FILE argument. However, `{print > FILE".new"}` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

header=$1; shift

for pathname do
    { printf '%s\n' "$header"; cat -- "$pathname"; } >"$pathname.new"
done
```

There is no real need for `awk` here as we want to concatenate the header and the old file contents.  We do this by simply outputting the header string with `printf` and then using `cat` to output the file's contents.  We redirect the output of both `printf` and `cat` to a new file.

Would you *really* want to do it with `awk`, then either loop over the files as in the code above, or let `awk` process each file without an explicit shell loop.

First variation with an explicit shell loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

header=$1; shift

for pathname do
    header=$header awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["header"] }; 1' "$pathname" >"$pathname.new"
done
```

The above solution would be the slowest variant of all variants in this answer, as it invokes `awk` once per file.

Second variation without a shell loop (requires an `awk` that understands `BEGINFILE`, like GNU `awk` does):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

header=$1; shift

header=$header awk '
    BEGINFILE { fname = FILENAME ".new"; print ENVIRON["header"] >(fname) }
    { print >(fname) }' "$@"
```

Third variation (portable variant of the last piece of code):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

header=$1; shift

header=$header awk '
    FNR == 1 { fname = FILENAME ".new"; print ENVIRON["header"] >(fname) }
    { print >(fname) }' "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I will go for the first suggestion. One question, why cant we use `echo $header` instead of `printf`? Is it because of compatibility issues with `echo`?

Comment: @JiaGeng First of all, using `$header` unquoted may invoke word splitting and filename globbing (e.g. if the header is `* * * hello * * *`, each `*` will be globbing).  Secondly, `echo` may change the data before printing it (interpreting certain backspace sequences like `\t` and `\n`). Thirdly, if the header is simply `-n`, you'd get unexpected results.  See also more details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this, assuming you have no empty input files, would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
header=$1 
shift 

awk -v header="$header" '
    FNR==1 { close(out); out=FILENAME ".new"; $0=header ORS $0 }
    { print > out }
' "$@"
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box. If you can have empty input files it'd need a tweak.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the modified version which works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

header=$1
shift

for file in $@; do 
    awk -v HEADER="$header" 'BEGIN{print HEADER} {print}' "$file" > "$file".new
done
```

I tried to use `{print > [FILE].new}` inside the awk expression but it did not work. It just printed to `stdout`. Maybe because new files cannot be created within awk.

Comment: You need to quote `$@`, or you won't be able to cope with filename containing whitespace or filename globbing characters.